# 2 client + 1 Server game in Android with webserver in PHP

Tags: java, php, android, client-server

I am trying to build an Android app with 2 clients and 1 server. The design is as follows:

1. Client 1 log-in.
2. Client 2 log-in.
3. Client 1 inputs some text that needs to be validated by server through MySQL db.
4. Based on the server response, server sends some result to Client 2.

this happens back and forth till game ends.

both the clients are android mobile devices. I am able to establish a 1 client (Java) + server (PHP) + MySQL connection and it is working fine. But now I am getting confused on how do I implement the notion of 2 clients in my app interacting with the same server.

Comment: What are you having trouble with?  They both should hit the same web services. If you need to know which is which, have them send a unique token with each message-  ANDROID_ID would work fine.

Comment: php is not ideally suited for this but you may want to lookup php's socket library, specifically the `select()` http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am new to PHP so I dnt know how to redirect the response to a particular client. I am able to hit the same web service from both the clients and will see the ANDROID_ID stuff as well. Is it possible for you to point me to some sample code showing me the client specific response.

Comment: RMI has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some important use cases are missing:

- What happen if more than two clients are connected?
- How Client 1 knows about Client 2 and how does he start the game with him?
- What happen if one of the client disconnected?

Usually the answers to these use cases show that your server has states, at least you need to handle the state of the logged in clients and the state of the active games.

You can implement it with PHP and MySQL but you would probably find yourself spending most of your time handling issues related to the architecture rather than adding new features.
I would recommend selecting better framework, at least Servlets.

However, if you still want to do it in PHP and without answering the above use cases:

- Once logged in, start a pulling mechanism: every x seconds the client ask the server if it has information for him, and perform a suitable action according to the response.
- Add a responses table to the server, whenever you have something to tell a client, add the client ID and the response to this table.
- You would probably need a table for logged in users and a table for the states of the games.

Client 1 logged in and start pulling

- Client 1 response: do nothing

Client 2 logged in and start pulling

- Client 1 response: send text
- Client 2 response: do nothing

Client 1 send text

- Client 1 response: do nothing
- Client 2 response: result

Client 2 send text

- Client 1 response: result
- Client 2 response: do nothing

etc.

There are other ways but again, in my opinion PHP is not the right solution here.

Hope this helps, Yaron